# What does $$, $?, $^ represent in powershell?

Tags: powershell

Saw these variables in the debugger and I'm not sure what they do.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

- `$_`  The current pipeline object; used in script blocks, filters, the process clause of functions, where-object, foreach-object and switch
- `$^`      contains the first token of the last line input into the shell
- `$$`      contains the last token of last line input into the shell
- `$?`      Contains the success/fail status of the last statement

[Source](https://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/variables/#PowerShells_$Dollar_Variables_)

Comment: I guess the description for `$_` could be shortened to "used in script blocks". All the other listed cases are script blocks as well.

Comment: I get $_ and $? now, but why would I ever use $^ or $$?

Comment: @Micah it's more useful in an interactive prompt
`Test-Connection -ComputerName somecomputer`
`mstsc /v $$` <- connects to `somecomputer`

Comment: The link in this post is now broken. The content is still on the site, but the URL is now https://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/variables/ - or you might prefer an archived version. I admit I found https://web.archive.org/web/20101122001258/http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_variables.htm#%24Dollar_variables_ to be the easier-to-read option. I can't edit either URL in because the edit queues are full, so if someone else sees this could they please do it?

Comment: @AJM updated the link. Thank you!

Comment: @MattBall No - thank YOU!

Answer (score 11):

Read

```
Get-Help About_Automatic_Variables
```

Its all about the goodness of automatic variables that get created when using PowerShell console.

Comment: Those aren't specific to the console host.

Comment: This is valuable info once you actually know that they are referred to as "Automatic Variables" _and_ once you actually ran Update-Help in your Powershell console as Administrator _and_ are lucky enough that you can actually update given the currently running Culture. Otherwise, there is no way you actually would ever figure this out ;).

Answer (score 5):

In PowerShell, a dollar sign preceding a name indicates a variable. The symbols in question are just special cases of variables provided by the PowerShell environment. They are also known as "automatic" variables. More specifically:

- `$$` is a variable containing the last token of the last line input into the shell
  (does not contain the whole command)
- `$^` is a variable containing the first token of the last line input into the shell
  (does not contain the whole command)
- `$?` is a variable containing the success or failure of the last statement
  (`False` if the previous command ended with an error; `True` otherwise.)

Comment: "True if the previous command ended with an error; False otherwise" Really?