# Concat variable inside string in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to concat variable in the string.

**Code** :

```
$uniqueID = "123"
$Key = '<add key="uniqueID" value="$uniqueID" />'
write-host $Key
```

**Result i want** :

```
<add key="uniqueID" value="123" />
```

**Result i am getting** :

```
<add key="uniqueID" value="$uniqueID" />
```

Comment: `$Key = "<add key='uniqueID' value='$uniqueID' />"`. Better yet, don't build your XML by string concatenation. PowerShell comes with an XML parser. Use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this -

```
$Key = "<add key=`"uniqueID`" value=`"$($uniqueID)`" />"
```

**OR**

```
$Key = "<add key=`"uniqueID`" value=`"$uniqueID`" />"
```

To force Windows PowerShell to interpret a double quotation mark
literally, use a backtick character. This prevents Windows PowerShell
from interpreting the quotation mark as a string delimiter.

**INFO -**

If you look at `Get-Help about_Quoting_Rules`, it says,

```
SINGLE AND DOUBLE-QUOTED STRINGS
   When you enclose a string in double quotation marks (a double-quoted
   string), variable names that are preceded by a dollar sign ($) are
   replaced with the variable's value before the string is passed to the
   command for processing.

   For example:

       $i = 5
       "The value of $i is $i."

   The output of this command is:
       The value of 5 is 5.

   Also, in a double-quoted string, expressions are evaluated, and the
   result is inserted in the string. For example:

       "The value of $(2+3) is 5."

   The output of this command is:

       The value of 5 is 5.

   When you enclose a string in single-quotation marks (a single-quoted
   string), the string is passed to the command exactly as you type it.
   No substitution is performed. For example:

       $i = 5
       'The value of $i is $i.'

   The output of this command is:

       The value $i is $i.

   Similarly, expressions in single-quoted strings are not evaluated. They
   are interpreted as literals. For example:

       'The value of $(2+3) is 5.'

   The output of this command is:

       The value of $(2+3) is 5.
```

The reason your code wasn't evaluating the value was because you were using a single quote to wrap the variable `$key`. Wrapping it with double quote and using a [sub-expression operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242161/what-does-represent-in-powershell) (`$($UniqueID`) along with backtick does the trick, or simply using the `$UniqueID` will also suffice.

Comment: This will give me : <add key='uniqueID' value='123' /> but i need double quotes instead of single.

Comment: You can use a backtick to treat double quotes as literal values. Check out the solution now.

Comment: Note that you can also use `""quoted text""` without using a backtick as well (gets rendered as `"quoted text"`). this also works in single quoted strings for single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

I find using the '-f' formatting option works great for this kind of request.  Try:

```
$uniqueID = "123"
$Key = ('<add key="{0}" value="{1}" />' -f 'uniqueID', $uniqueID)
write-host $Key
```