# How do I make the hello world execute in C# terminal

Tags: c#, terminal

am trying to find out why my C# 'hello world' program isn't running after installation and set up. this is my code below

```
using System;

namespace mysharpproject // Note: actual namespace depends on the project name.
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

this is the error the error am getting:   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand

PS C:\Users\check> cd "c:\Users\check\Desktop\mysharpproject" $$ dotnet run tempCodeRunnerFile.cs
Set-Location : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Program.cs'.
At line:1 char:1

- cd "c:\Users\check\Desktop\mysharpproject" $$ dotnet run tempCodeRun ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Location], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
  ```

PS C:\Users\check>

Comment: I've never used `dotnet run`, but the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run shows that it should be most simply run either in a directory with a project file (`.csproj`) and no arguments or with an argument specifying a project file. You've specified the source code file.

Answer (score 2):

THis command

```
cd "c:\Users\check\Desktop\mysharpproject" $$ dotnet run tempCodeRunnerFile.cs
```

includes '$$' that means the last part part of the previous command, why are you doing that?

[What does $$, $?, $^ represent in powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242161/what-does-represent-in-powershell)

Just do

```
cd "c:\Users\check\Desktop\mysharpproject" ; dotnet run tempCodeRunnerFile.cs
```

Comment: this was what I did. [1]  opened the project folder [2] in the addressline on tope of the folder, I typed, cmd. [when the cmd executed, i typed the following without the quotes "dotnet  new console" and hit enter. after that was executed, i type in the command line 'code .' without the quotes and hit enter, and then clicked on the 'terminal' on tope of the ide and clicked new terminal.